# Can't stop video after closing modal in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to stop each video after closing a modal by getting the id of each element with javascript, but it just works for the last video.

Here's the html for both videos with modal:

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
   <div class="popup">
       <h2>3B - Bum Bum Brasil</h2>
       <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
       <div class="content">
  <center>  <video width="90%" id="video" height="90%" controls>
<source src="videos/3b.mp4" type="video/mp4">

 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></center>
       </div>
 </div></div>

<div id="popup2" class="overlay">
   <div class="popup">
       <h2>Six Pack</h2>
       <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
       <div class="content">
  <center>  <video width="90%" id="video2" height="90%" controls>
<source src="videos/sixpack.mp4" type="video/mp4">

 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></center>
       </div>
 </div></div>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
<script>
   var video = document.getElementById("video");
 function stopVid(){
      video.pause();
      video.currentTime = 0;

 }

var video2 = document.getElementById("video2");
 function stopVid(){
      video2.pause();
      video2.currentTime = 0;

 }


   $(".close").on('click', function(){
   stopVid();

   }
   );


      </script>
```

Comment: can you please reproduce the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and congratulations on your first question.

Working with multiple `id` values can be cumbersome if you have a dynamic page with an unfixed amount of elements that you want to manipulate. So unless the `<video>` element is on a whole different section of the page and there is no other way than selecting it with `getElementById`, then I suggest that take a different approach.

Both the `.close` and `video` elements are both children (or grandchildren) of the `.popup` element. This is useful information! This makes the use of *event delegation* very promising.

Most events *bubble*. This means that, for example, when a child fires a `click` event then the event will travel upward through each parent until it reaches the `<html>` tag. Now we can listen for the click on a child and handle it from the parent. Like listen for the click on `.close`, but handle it from each `.popup`. No more need for `id` values.

Select all the `.popup` elements. Loop over them and listen to their `click` events with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). **Don't use jQuery and Vanilla JavaScript intertwined**, and in my opinion: It's better to learn Vanilla anyway for it will make you understand better how JavaScript works.

In the function for the `click` event you'll want to know if the `.close` button has been clicked. If it has, then stop the video. If not, then do nothing. Each event gives you an `Event` object. This object gives you info about the type of event, what element triggered the event, mouse position, etc.

The `event.target` property is the clicked element which triggered the event. We can check if it is the `.click` button by using the [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method on it. If it is not the element we are looking for it will return `null`. Otherwise we're solid.

Then use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) from the current popup to find the video inside of it. You have your video! Now you can pass that to your `stopVid` function and pause it.

The example below shows you all steps mentioned above in code. Please let me know if I have been unclear or you have any questions.

```
// Get all popup <div> elements.
const popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popup'); 

/**
 * This stop function needs to know which 
 * <video> element you want to stop.
 */
function stopVideo(video) {
  video.pause();
  video.currentTime = 0;
}

/**
 * When clicking inside the popup, check
 * if the .close button is clicked. If it
 * is then pause the video if it is present.
 */
function onPopupClick(event) {
  const popup = this; // 'this' is element we are listening to.
  const close = event.target.closest('.close');
  if (close === null) {
    return; // Stop the function.
  }
  const video = popup.querySelector('video');
  if (video !== null) {
    stopVideo(video);
  }
}

// Loop over each popup.
for (const popup of popups) {
  popup.addEventListener('click', onPopupClick);
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

$() Selector returns an array of elements. You have to write the index to the needed element.

If only one element with class *close* exists on your page, then access like that

```
$('.close')[0].on('click', function(){
   stopVid();
})
```

Otherwise you have to work with id's

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that defining a new `stopVid` function overrides the first one so only the latest `stopVid` function works.
A workaround for this problem would be defining a more generic function for closing and stopping videos. Note that my solution requires that the close buttons have the attribute `video` with the value of the id of the corresponding video element. See my solution below:

```js
<script>
  function stopVid(id){
    let video = document.getElementById(id);
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
  }


  $(".close").forEach(c => {
    c.on('click', function(e){
      let id = e.target.getAttribute('video')
      stopVid(id);
    });
  });
</script>
```